# Function to find regex matches in text prints one match at a time... I need a list

Tags: python, regex, xml, findall

The function I created to find a list of regex matches doesn't work: instead of printing a list of all the matches, it prints one match at a time. I tried multiple times and I don't understand what the error could be.

For instance, this is the text I want to find the regex in: `'] prima ciao hello'`

This is the function:

```
def find_regex(regex, text):
l = []
matches_prima = re.findall(regex, text)
lunghezza_prima = len(matches_prima)
for x in matches_prima:
    l.extend(matches_prima)

print(l)
```

And in another function is called like:

```
def main():

        testo = '] prima ciao hello', 'ola'

        find_prima = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima(?!\S)")


        print(find_regex(find_prima,testo))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So given a regex, I call it like `print(find_regex(find_prima,testo))`. But the output is:

```
    ['] prima']
[]
```

So I get them printed once at a time.

And I would need the full list instead to count all the matches. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read [mcve] carefully. Then edit the question and provide an example that really is minimal, complete, and reproducible.

Comment: Ok, I tried to make it better, but it's not easy as my code is more complex

Comment: You're passing an array to findall(), this doesnt work

Comment: How to solve this?

Comment: As suggested by @mzjn, can you share the desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import re

txt = """mypattern, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquip sunt ad irure ad
labore nulla do et est eiusmod ut fugiat. Minim enim incididunt ullamco
deserunt Lorem cillum in est ullamco dolor qui sint labore. Reprehenderit
laborum anim magna pariatur proident cillum et eiusmod eu laboris cillum.
Quis et nostrud laboris non. Est incididunt dolore sint dolore. Sunt eu
mypattern, ipsum ullamco dolore ad ut veniam est. dolore mollit ut sunt nulla
"""


print([line for line in txt.splitlines() if re.match(r"mypattern, ", line) is not None])
```

Output:

```
['mypattern, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquip sunt ad irure ad', 'mypattern, ipsum ullamco dolore ad ut veniam est. dolore mollit ut sunt nulla']
```